# Laravel URL Generation Not Including Parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm seeing an issue with Laravel 4 when I have two routes pointing to the same action, one within a group and one just "loose" in the routes.php file.

```
<?php     

// Routes.php
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.domain.com'), function()
{
        Route::get('profile/{id}/{name}', 'ProfileController@index');
});

Route::get('profile/{id}/{name}', 'ProfileController@index');

// Template.blade.php
<a href="{{ URL::action('ProfileController@index', array(123, 'JimSmith')) }}">Jim Smith</a>
```

The template links to: `currentsubdomain.domain.com/profile/%7Bid%7D/%7Bname%7D` instead of the expected behaviour of swapping the ID and name for 123 and JimSmith respectively.

If I comment out, the first route (the one within the group), the code works as expected. Why does adding this additional route break the URL generation? Is there a way to work around this? Am I missing something obvious?

P.s. For those wondering why I need this route in two places it's so I can optionally generate the url with the subdomain using `URL::action('ProfileController@index' array('subdomain' => 'james', 'id' => 123, 'name' => 'JimSmith');`

Comment: I'm not too sure why, but you could use named routes as an alternative. `Route::get('profile/{id}/{name}', array('as' => 'yourname', 'uses' => 'YourController@method'));` Then in your template you can do `{{ route('yourname') }}` to output the URL. You can pass in your extra arguments to the route as normal: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls

Comment: What happens if you comment out the *second* route and leave only the first one? Does it still not work? In other words, is it having *both* that causes the problem or is it having *the first one* that causes it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have names/aliases for the routes so it's defaulting to the first one it comes across.

Consider this an alternate route structure:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.domain.com'), function() {
    Route::get('profile/{id}/{name}', [
        'as' => 'tenant.profile.index',
        'uses' => 'ProfileController@index'
    ]);
});

Route::get('profile/{id}/{name}', [
    'as' => 'profile.index',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@index'
]);
```

Now that you have these routes named, you can do:

```
{{ URL::route('profile.index', [123, 'jSmith']) }}
```

Or alternatively:

```
{{ URL::route('tenant.profile.index', ['subdomain', 123, 'jSmith']) }}
```

As just an added extra, you could only have this route defined once, then in all the controller methods you'd have something like:

```
public function index($subdomain = null, $id, $name) { }
```

Then you can just simply pass `www` through as the subdomain and have some code somewhere that discounts the www.domain.com domain from certain actions.

Multi-tenancy (if that is indeed what you're after) isn't easy and straight forward but there are some methods used to tackle certain parts. I'm actually planning on writing a tutorial regarding it, but for now I hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Thanks for the info, in the end we couldn't use two different names as then the path matches the first (subdomain.domain.com) and passes the subdomain into the controller, so I went with your second suggestion, defining the route only once and defaulting the subdomain.